# Hanging Excel.exe process in automated program

Tags: c#, .net, excel, comobject

```
var tempFileName = file.Replace(".xlsx", "_Temp.xlsx");
Application excelApp = new Application();
Workbooks books = excelApp.Workbooks;
Workbook excelFile = books.Open(file);
Sheets sheets = excelFile.Worksheets;
var app = excelApp.Application;
DeleteRows(sheets, 3);
excelFile.SaveAs(tempFileName);
excelFile.Close();
books.Close();
app.Quit();
excelApp.Quit();
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(sheets);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelFile);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(books);
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
sheets = null;
excelFile = null;
excelApp = null;
books = null;
```

I am trying to dispose of my excel objects, however even the above code still leaves me with hanging EXCEL.EXE processes after the program has finished running. I have seen this question on here a number of times, but most of the askers had not tried the `ReleaseComObject()` method, however that did not fix anything for me.

EDIT: This is the code i use to read the table after deleting the header

```
  System.Data.DataTable schemaTable = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
  DataRow schemaRow = schemaTable.Rows[0];
  string sheet = schemaRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
  if (!sheet.EndsWith("_"))
  {
      string query = "SELECT  * FROM [Daily Payment$]";
      OleDbDataAdapter daexcel = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection);
      dtexcel.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
      daexcel.Fill(dtexcel);
      var reader = dtexcel.CreateDataReader();
```

and here is the code for DeleteRows:

```
void DeleteRows(Sheets sheets, int n)
{ 
    foreach (Worksheet workSheet in sheets)
    {
        Range range = workSheet.get_Range("A1", "A" + n);
        Range row = range.EntireRow;
        row.Delete(XlDirection.xlUp);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workSheet);
    }
}
```

FINAL EDIT: I have reposted the new code that I have at the top of the post. I am still getting one lingering object (even though i run the process multiple times). Calling Gc.Collect() works, but as a relative neophyte, i figured it was best to avoid something so powerful.

Comment: You don't need Excel to read or generate Excel files. Excel's format, `xlsx`, was created to allow developers to generate XLSX files without Excel installed, eg on web servers, reporting applications, etc. You can generate a new `xlsx` file with the Open XML SDK or a library like EPPlus. Creating a new file from a datatable or collecion can be as easy as calling `sheet.LoadFromCollection(myListOfObjects);`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i'm importing an xlsx file and OleDb connection to excel wont read the data with this annoying header that comes on the file. So i open the file, and delete the 3 rows (aka the header) then save it as a temp file (because i want the original one preserved for the archives). Then i close the file and use the oledb connection to read the data.

Comment: You don't need to open the file, you can select from a range of cells, eg `Select * From [MySheet$B4:E313]`. You can use a named range or table name instead of a cell range. You don't need Excel to delete rows, use the SDK or EPPlus to load and edit the file. Post your query

Comment: Use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/), [ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml), [Aspose.Cells](https://www.aspose.com/products/cells/net), or [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx). Dealing directly with Excel is a mistake if you don't need to actually have the Excel GUI.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i added my query where DailyPayments is the name of the workbook

Comment: Can you specify the cell range too? You could write eg `"SELECT  * FROM [Daily Payment$A4:E100]"` to avoid the first 3 rows. If the data range is named or marked as a table, you can use that name, eg `SELECT  * FROM [MY_RANGE]`

Comment: I have no way of knowing the lower limit as the files are variable in length

Comment: Also when i try and open an OleDBConnection to the original file (with the stupid header), i get the following exception: 'External table is not in the expected format.'

Comment: Please see edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For freeing Office COM interop objects, you can go by the 'one release per `.` rule'. That is, when you have a chain of member accesses, you need to free all the intermediate objects.

This often means splitting up your code into additional lines.

Following that rule, you're missing one. You need to keep a handle to the `Workbooks` object you've implicitly created.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbooks books = excelApp.Workbooks;
Workbook excelFile = books.Open(file);
DeleteRows(excelFile, 3);
```

Then you need to call:

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(books);
```

at the end.

Failing this, you can also try calling:

```
books.Close()
```

before you quit Excel. And to go overkill, you can change all your `ReleaseComObject` calls to `FinalReleaseComObject`.

EDIT:
In your newly posted update, you are not releasing your `Row` or `Range` objects. Call `FinalReleaseComObject` on these, and I'd expect the problem to be solved.

Comment: The best option is to avoid using Excel entirely.

Comment: @JacobAlley: Try with what I've added in the update.

Comment: i did and no love. Although now there is only 1 total Excel process lingering no matter how many files I import, before it was creating one for every file

Comment: Is it possible there's a popup stopping Excel from closing correctly? Try getting it to display the process so that you can see; I believe it's `excelApp.Visible = true` in c#

Comment: posted the code for delete rows....and doing visible does not show any lingering popups that need to be addressed or anything like that

Comment: Can't see the DeleteRows function in your post still. :(

Comment: How about now??

Comment: Great. Explicitly Release the Range and Row objects inside the loop, and you should be all good.

Comment: Sick, that did it. Wow was that annoying.

Comment: It is indeed. In the past I spent many long hours figuring this all out! Good luck with the project!